# writing conditions within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I just started to learn Angular JS and im preparing a test library system and have a small issue with the ng-repeat

I have 2 tables. One stores details about books and the other is the student who has borrowed the book.

Table 1- `book_id, book_name, borrowed, student_id`

Table 2 -  `book_id, student_ name, student_id`

There are 2 separate functions that take all the details from each of the above tables.

Below code which shows all the books which is grabbed from the first table

```
<div class=”available” ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.book_name}}</div>
```

What Im trying to do is

```
If  borrowed == 1
```

Change the class="not_available" and add the student_name and the book_name inside the div which needs to be grabbed from student which has the student details.

JS Code

```
 function studentsController($scope,$http) {
     $scope.students = [];
     $http.get('<?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_students'); ?>').success(function($data){ $scope.students=$data; });
 }

  function booksController($scope,$http) {
     $scope.books = [];
     $http.get('<?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_books'); ?>').success(function($data){ $scope.books=$data; });
 }
```

I did try the `filter` and `ng-if`, but I was unable to achieve the above

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post your javascript as well? What information do you have in the book object? To change the class you use ng-class. Replace `class="available"` with `ng-class="book.borrowed == 1 ? 'not_available' : 'available'"`

Comment: @Razzildinho the book object has` the id, book_name, borrowed, student_id` details.... Il try the ng-class thing :)

Comment: Checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two array

- first one is `books` for : `book_id, book_name, borrowed, student_id`
- second one is `students` for : `book_id, student_ name, student_id`

then go to this below way to achieve your concepts (*just take this as a key*)

```
<div class="available" ng-repeat="book in books">
    {{book.book_name}}
    <div ng-repeat="student in students ">
        <div class="not_available"  ng-show="student.book_id==book.book_id>
          {{book.book_name}} is already purchased by {{student.student_ name}}
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Il try that :) by the way, what is meant by `**` ?

Comment: Don't mind it. I try to bold to that line. remove it

Answer (score 1):

I would put it all in one controller to avoid having to reference one from the other.

```
function libraryController($scope,$http) {
  $scope.students = [];
  $http.get('<?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_students'); ?>').success(function($data){ $scope.students=$data; });

  $scope.books = [];
  $http.get('<?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_books'); ?>').success(function($data){ $scope.books=$data; });

  $scope.getBookBorrowerName = function(book){
    for (var s=0; s<$scope.students.length; s++){
      if (book.student_id == $scope.students[s].student_id){
        return ' - Borrowed by: ' + $scope.students[s].student_name;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

And then your html would be something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books" ng-class="book.borrowed != 1 ? 'available' : 'not_available'">{{book.book_name + book.borrowed == 1 ? getBookBorrowerName(book) : ''}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... Can u let me know what does this mean `book.book_name + book.borrowed == 1` ?

Comment: @LiveEn It's a piece of javascript to show the book name (`book.book_name`) followed by a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which shows the name of the student if the book is borrowed or an empty string if not (`book.borrowed == 1 ? getBookBorrowerName(book) : ''`)

Comment: ah ok... thank you.. Just an error.. when i run it  `SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control for (var s=0; s<$scope.students.length; s++;)` any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
angular.module('moduleName')
.controller('ctrName', [function($scope) {
   $scope.books = [......];
   $scope.students = [......];

   $scope.getStuDetailsByBookId = function(book_id, prop) {
     // some login to get student object from students collection
     return studenDetails[prop];
   };
}]);


<div ng-controller="nameController">
   <div ng-repeat="book in books" ng-class="{'not-avail': book.borrowed == 1, 'other' : book.borrowed != 1}">
     <div ng-if="book.borrowed == 1">
      {{getStuDetailsByBookId(book.book_id, 'name')}}
      {{getStuDetailsByBookId(book.book_id, 'id')}}
     </div>
   </div>

</div>
```